# Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' Tried calling: []("main")

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have made all the necessary changes but still it is showing the same error , please help !!`

[This is the image to get url using http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMpcL.png)

[image: This is used to fetch api from openWeatherMap]

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Try to [edit] the question and copy-paste it instead in between 3 backticks - \`\`\` code \`\`\`. Also, where exactly the error is being thrown?

Comment: I am not getting it that where the error has been thrown it's probably in Future <dynamic> but how to resolve it

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste the `NetworkHelper` into it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.